# Flutter WEB app: Firebase no longer deploying on tools version 12.5.2

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting

New on firebase. I was able to deploy my flutter web app before, now after I've updated to the version 12.5.2 my terminal stops without any deployment and I am getting an automatic pop-up in my notepad showing a code text.

I have done the normal process I used to do it:

```
Firebase login, 
Firebase init (select public build/web)
Flutter build web -t lib/app/main.dart (location of my main.dart file)
Firebase deploy --only hosting
```

The terminal seems have stopped. as the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iSwy.png)

Part of the notepad text is:

```
if (!_flutter) {
  var _flutter = {};
}
_flutter.loader = null;

(function () {
 "use strict";

 const baseUri = ensureTrailingSlash(getBaseURI());

 function getBaseURI() {
   const base = document.querySelector("base");
  return (base && base.getAttribute("href")) || "";
 }

  function ensureTrailingSlash(uri) {
    if (uri == "") {
     return uri;
   }
    return uri.endsWith("/") ? uri : `${uri}/`;
  }`

 /**
  * Wraps `promise` in a timeout of the given `duration` in ms.
  *
  * Resolves/rejects with whatever the original `promises` does, or rejects
  * if `promise` takes longer to complete than `duration`. In that case,
  * `debugName` is used to compose a legible error message.
  *
  * If `duration` is < 0, the original `promise` is returned unchanged.
 * @param {Promise} promise
 * @param {number} duration
 * @param {string} debugName
 * @returns {Promise} a wrapped promise.
 */
  async function timeout(promise, duration, debugName) {
    if (duration < 0) {
      return promise;
   }
    let timeoutId;
   const _clock = new Promise((_, reject) => {
      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    reject(
      new Error(
        `${debugName} took more than ${duration}ms to resolve. Moving on.`,
        {
          cause: timeout,
        }
        )
       );
     }, duration);
    }); ....

     return Promise.race([promise, _clock]).finally(() => {
     clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    });
   }
```

I tried to deploy my flutter web app in firebase as the previous version